# How can anti-aliasing be enabled in a pyqtgraph ImageView?

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I'm using `pyqtgraph`'s `ImageView` widget to display an image that needs to be scaled up by a factor of 1.25 to 1.5 to be comfortably viewed. This makes the nearest-neighbor sampling of the image obvious and distracting. The `setAutoDownsample` method on the `ImageItem` instance inside of the `ImageView` instance helps when a large image is scaled very small. But *how can I enable anti-aliasing to improve the appearance of a small image that's being scaled up?*

I have tried calling the `setAntialiasing` method of the `GraphicsView` instance inside the `ImageView` instance, but this has no effect. It may be due to the note in the documentation:

> Note that this will only affect items that do not specify their own antialiasing options.

But I cannot understand what items in the `GraphicsView` might have their own options, or how to change these.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue and found that enabling antialising globally did the trick:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, it looked so raw without it